# Write byte at address (hexedit/modify binary from the command line)

Tags: shell, scripting, hex, patch, edit

Is there any straightforward way to modify a binary from the commandline?

Let's say I know that my binary contains 1234ABCD and I want to change it to 12FFABCD or FFFFABCD or maybe even FF34FFABC0 (you get the idea) :-)

How might I achieve that without using any special purpose tools like [Swiss File Knife](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html) or similar?

It would be great to do it just from the command line with only standard Linux tools.

Or maybe even better, instead for searching for the hexadecimal string I want to replace directly writing FF at *offset* 0x10000, 12 at *offset* 0x100001 and so on.

It should be scriptable and run directly from the command line. I am looking for something like "binary-which-is-included-in-the-distro --write AB --at-offset 100000 --file thebinary.bin". I am quite sure that it is possible with [dd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29), but I wasn't able to wrap my head around the [man page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).

Answer (score 130):

```
printf '\x31\xc0\xc3' | dd of=test_blob bs=1 seek=100 count=3 conv=notrunc
```

[dd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) arguments:

- **of** | file to patch
- **bs** | 1 byte at a time please
- **seek** | go to position 100 (decimal)
- **conv=notrunc** | don't truncate the output after the edit (which dd does by default)

One Josh looking out [for another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4783657) ;)

Comment: Beautiful elegant solution!   Is it possible to insert bytes using this command as well?  Or to output the patched file to a different filename?   Or for the seek position to be based on a variable like the filesize?

Comment: This is a great solution, but sadly, it doesn't work with BusyBox. BusyBox's implementation of dd doesn't support conv=notrunc (or conv=anything, for that matter).

Comment: Be sure to note that seek may not be in bytes, but in the size of obs.

Comment: @AdamHaun BusyBox's dd does support some conv= options, including conv=notrunc, and I have verified that this solution works with BusyBox in its default configuration (BusyBox is very configurable and this feature can be disabled in custom builds).

Comment: This overwrites data. To append data at a specific position instead, the second solution of this answer worked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276339/how-do-i-append-data-to-a-binary-file-with-an-hex-editor/1276363#1276363

Comment: Great solution! However, how to patch a data going to another program using a pipe? E.g. in `echo "char* x = \"xxx\";" | gcc -xc - -c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` how to patch `xxx` to `x<null>x`?

Comment: this is wrong... if the original file length is 300, this code will truncate the original file to 100

Answer (score 13):

The `printf + dd` based solutions do not seem to work for writing out zeros. Here is a generic solution in Python 3 (included in all modern distributions) which should work for all byte values...

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#file: set-byte

import sys

fileName = sys.argv[1]
offset = int(sys.argv[2], 0)
byte = int(sys.argv[3], 0)

with open(fileName, "r+b") as fh:
    fh.seek(offset)
    fh.write(bytes([byte]))
```

Usage...

```
set-byte eeprom_bad.bin 0x7D00 0
set-byte eeprom_bad.bin 1000 0xff
```

Note: This code can handle input numbers both in hexadecimal (prefixed by 0x) and decimal (no prefix).

Comment: Important you run this in python3 (not python2) or else you end up writing literal string representation of a list: `[byte]`

Comment: The query was for Shell script, not Python script.

Comment: The printf+dd works when writing out zeros, for this is mandatory to use the "conv=notrunc" option.

Comment: printf '\x00\x00\x00\x00' | dd of=blah bs=1 seek=24 count=4 conv=notrunc works (Linux Mint 20)

Comment: Support for hex in printf depends on the printf implementation. Bash built-in printf supports it, as does GNU printf (the one found as /usr/bin/printf in many Linux). But the built-in printf in some sh variants (like dash) doesn't support it. Octal should be supported by all variants, though. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html for the POSIX explanation. So an alternative is to use something else, e.g. xxd or perl, to output the stream to "poke" with dd.

Comment: This works in out-of-the-box Ubuntu 20: `printf '\x00\x00\x00\x00' | dd of=somefile bs=1 seek=4 count=4 conv=notrunc`

Answer (score 10):

Here's a Bash function `replaceByte`, which takes the following parameters:

- the name of the file,
- an offset of the byte in the file to rewrite, and
- the new value of the byte (a number).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# param 1: file
# param 2: offset
# param 3: value
function replaceByte() {
    printf "$(printf '\\x%02X' $3)" | dd of="$1" bs=1 seek=$2 count=1 conv=notrunc &> /dev/null
}

# Usage:
# replaceByte 'thefile' $offset 95
```

Answer (score 4):

The [xxd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) tool, which comes with [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) (and thus is quite likely to be available) allows to hex dump a binary file and construct a new binary file from a modified hex dump.

Comment: But that also wouldn't work from the commandline (see my comment above to Dans reply), right?

Comment: It should work: `xxd -ps ... | sed -s "s/.../.../g/" | xxd -r ...`

Comment: For your case: `echo "010000: FF" | xxd -r - binary.x`

Comment: I like this one because it also allows me to do simple search and replace on hex data when I don't know the exact location.

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives:

- [HexAlter](http://gamehacking.org/downloads/HexAlter.zip) (open source compiled tool)
- `ucon64 --nbak --poke=OFF:V FILE` ([meant for ROM dumps](http://ucon64.sourceforge.net/ucon64/readme.html), should work with any binary file, but no inplace editing)
- `printf '\x31' | dd of=FILE bs=1 seek=OFFSET count=1 conv=notrunc` ([wrapped in a shellscript like this that also allows reading](http://eadmaster.altervista.org/pub/index.php?page=cliapps#hex))

Answer (score 2):

Writing the same byte at two different positions in the same file with a one liner.

```
printf '\x00'| tee >(dd of=filename bs=1 count=1 seek=692 conv=notrunc status=none) \
    >(dd of=filename bs=1 count=1 seek=624 conv=notrunc status=none)
```

**status=none** very useful when you don't want any statistics out of dd.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need it to be scriptable, you could try the [hexedit](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hexedit) utility. It is available in many Linux distributions (if not installed by default, it can usually be found in the distribution's package repository).

If your distribution doesn't have it, you can [build and install it from source](http://rigaux.org/hexedit.html).

Comment: It should be scriptable and run directly from the commandline. I am looking for something like "binary-which-is-included-in-the-distro --write AB --at-offset 100000 --file thebinary.bin".

I am quite sure that it is possible with "dd", but I wasn't able to wrap my head around the man page.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783657/write-byte-at-address-hexedit-modify-binary-from-the-command-line/5586379#5586379): In case you want to do it for a specific address -

```
hexdump -C {file location}
```

with some hexadecimal value you might have tried to add 0x, but it would fail:

```
dd: warning: ‘0x’ is a zero multiplier; use ‘00x’ if that is intended
```

You can achieve this by encapsulating it with $(()) that the terminal will translate as an integer value:

```
mybinary={file location}
printf '\x31\xc0\xc3' | dd of=$mybinary bs=1 seek=$((0x100)) count=3 conv=notrunc
```