# Modify a byte in a binary file using standard Linux command-line tools

Tags: bash, shell, binary, edit, patch

I need to modify a byte in a binary file at a certain offset.

**Example:**

- Input file: `A.bin`
- Output file: `B.bin`

I need to read a byte at the offset `0x40c` from `A.bin`, clear to 0 least significant 2 bits of this byte, and then write file `B.bin` equal to `A.bin`, *but* with the calculated byte at offset `0x40c`.

- I can use Bash and standard commands like `printf` and [dd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29).
- I can easily [write a byte into a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783657/cli-write-byte-at-address-hexedit-modify-binary-from-the-command-line), but I don't know how to read it.

Modify a byte in a binary file using standard Linux command line tools.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155085/fetching-individual-bytes-from-a-binary-file-into-a-variable-with-bash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CLI: Write byte at address (hexedit/modify binary from the command line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783657/cli-write-byte-at-address-hexedit-modify-binary-from-the-command-line)

Comment: What is the question? It is stated as homework or a work order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```html
# Read one byte at offset 40C
b_hex=$(xxd -seek $((16#40C)) -l 1 -ps A.bin -)

# Delete the three least significant bits
b_dec=$(($((16#$b_hex)) & $((2#11111000))))
cp A.bin B.bin

# Write one byte back at offset 40C
printf "00040c: %02x" $b_dec | xxd -r - B.bin
```

It was tested in Bash and [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`) on OS X and Linux.

The last line explained:

- `00040c:` is the offset `xxd` should write to
- `%02x` converts `$b` from decimal to hexadecimal
- `xxd -r - B.bin`: reverse hexadecimal dump (`xxd -r`) — take the byte number and the hexadecimal value from standard input (`-`) and write to `B.bin`

Comment: I have upvoted your answer because I like it, but the OP asked for two different files, so `cp A.bin B.bin` should be put somewhere before the final `dd`, which would operate on `B.bin`; and, more importantly, this doesn’t work if `$b` equals ASCII NUL ...

Comment: @Dario thanks for pointing out that it should operate on a new file, added that in

Comment: @Dario woult it not work on `NUL`? `b=$(chr 0) && printf $b | dd of=B.bin seek=$((16#40C)) bs=1 count=1 conv=notrunc` works for me

Comment: I’m running BASH 4.3.30(1) on a Debian Jessie.  `echo abc >B.bin`; `xxd -ps B.bin` returns `6162630a`; `printf` (both builtin and `/usr/bin/printf`) gives error if I don’t quote the argument and `b=$(chr 0) && printf "$b" | dd of=B.bin seek=2 bs=1 count=1 conv=notrunc`; `xxd -ps B.bin` returns same as before. It also says `0 bytes (0 B) copied` which is the problem. There used to be no way to pass NULs either by `echo` or `printf`. Maybe this changed with later bash versions?

Comment: If I replace the last line of your script with `printf "00040c: %02x" $b | xxd -r - B.bin` it works in all cases, because if `$b` is NUL (or, equivalently for my shell, an empty string) it gets expanded by `%02x` as `00`. `xxd` is a standard command line tool as `dd` is.

Comment: @Dario thanks for the `xxd` suggestion. I altered the last line and also the reading. Now I don't need the `ord` function anymore so the code is now stripped down to 4 lines. Can you proofread that I didn't add any errors?

Comment: Seems to be OK.

Comment: Re *"take the line number"*: But it is a binary file(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen correct, I fixed it in the answer. Also: Thanks for the edit!