# Insert bytes into file using shell

Tags: shell, binary, printf, byte, dd

I would like to use a linux shell (bash, zsh, etc.) to insert a set of known bytes into a file at a certain position. [Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783657/cli-write-byte-at-address-hexedit-modify-binary-from-the-command-line?answertab=votes#tab-top) have been asked, but they modify in-place the bytes of a file. These questions don't address inserting new bytes at particular positions.

For example, if my file has a sequence of bytes like `\x32\x33\x35` I might want to insert `\x34` at position 2 so that this byte sequence in the file becomes `\x32\x33\x34\x35`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `head`, `tail` and `printf` together. For example; to insert `\x34` at position 2 in `file`:

```
{ head -c 2 file; printf '\x34'; tail -c +3 file; } > new_file
```

<sub>For POSIX-compliance, `\064` (octal representation of `\x34`) can be used.</sub>

To make this change in-place, just move `new_file` to `file`.

---

No matter which tool(s) you use, this operation will cost lots of CPU time for huge files.