# Swap or replace bytes in a binary file from command line

Tags: bash, shell, hex, patch, dd

There already is a beautiful trick in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783657/write-byte-at-address-hexedit-modify-binary-from-the-command-line)
to write bytes to binary file at desired address with *dd* ,is there any way to swap bytes(e.g swap *0x00* and *0xFF*), or replace bytes with common tools (such as *dd*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
xxd -p input_file | fold -w2 | perl -pe 's/00/ff/ || s/ff/00/' | xxd -r -p > output_file
```

- `xxd -p file` dumps the binary data `file` in continuous hexdump style.
- `fold -w2` wraps the input lines by every two characters (= every bytes).
- `perl -pe 's/00/ff/ || s/ff/00/'` swaps `00` and `ff` in the input string.
  The `||` logic works as `if .. else ..` condition. Otherwise the input `00`
  is once converted to `ff` and immediately converted back to `00` again.
- `xxd -r -p` is the reversed version of `xxd -p` which converts the input
  hexadecimal strings into binaries.